# Defer never called when writing to channel

Tags: go

I'm trying to write to a channel as last action in a goroutine function.

Unfortunately this is not working. And the waitGroup is never done.

```
import (
    "sync"
    "github.com/SlyMarbo/rss"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    urls := []string{"http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss", "http://rss.time.com/web/time/rss/top/index.xml"}

    var c = make(chan string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go receiveRss(url, &wg, c)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("==============DONE=================")
}

func receiveRss(url string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, c chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    feed, err := rss.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to retrieve RSS feed", err)
    }

    items := feed.Items
    for _, item := range items {
        c <- item.Title
    }
}
```

When replacing `c <- item.Title` with `fmt.Println(item.Title)` the deferred function is called and DONE is printed.

Comment: You don't have anything receiving from `c`.

Comment: To elaborate on @JimB 's comment, all your go-routines are blocking on `c <- item.Title ` because nothing is reading from the channel, so they never complete and the defer is never called, so main blocks waiting for the `WaitGroup`.

Comment: @MarcelCliff and after you added it - `c` is never closed so `for title := range c` is blocked forever.

Comment: I've figured it out now. Thank you. Reading the channel before ```wg.Wait()``` and closing this channel after the loop writing to it solves the problem.

Please post the solution as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @MarcelCliff - you are allowed to post your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I was only writing to the channel. Never reading from it.
Without doing this the channel would be useless.

The solution to this is:

Reading from the channel after the loop which starts the goroutines:

```
for title := range c {
    fmt.Println(title)
}
```

This then causes an endless loop if the channel is never closed.
So I just close the channel after writing to it:

```
close(c)
```

Here is the whole code:

```
func main() {

    urls := []string{"http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss", "http://rss.time.com/web/time/rss/top/index.xml"}

    var c = make(chan []string)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go receiveRss(url, &wg, c)
    }
    for title := range c {
        fmt.Println(title)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("==============DONE=================")
}

func receiveRss(url string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, c chan []string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    feed, err := rss.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to retrieve RSS feed", err)
    }

    items := feed.Items
    var titles []string
    for _, item := range items {
        titles = append(titles, item.Title)
    }
    c <- titles
    close(c)
}
```

Comment: wait a minute.. you just closed a channel still being used. that should panic on the next send though .. and also channels should only be closed once, but every goroutine calling receiveRss will call close in this case.